# Have configured two Wi-Fi access points, but they keep rebooting when both connected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

My house has flint walls which stop Wi-Fi signals and effectively divide the house into 3 parts.  I have therefore run ethernet from central router to the other two parts of the house and I am trying to use two old DSL-3680 routers as access points.

The main router (a Vodafone Wi-Fi hub) is 192.168.1.1 with a subnet of 255.255.255.0 and a DHCP pool of 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.200.  I have configured the other two routers with IP addresses of 192.168.1.7 and 192.168.1.8 (both subnet 255.255.255.0), I have put them into bridge mode and disabled the DHCP servers on them.  I have connected them to the central router via ethernet cables in one of the LAN ports.

With just one access point switched on, everything seems to work perfectly.  And initially when I switch both on everything works well.  I can access the admin pages of both routers from any device using their IP addresses; I can connect devices to them both using the other LAN port and Wi-Fi (which show up in the network-connected list of the main router with IP addresses in the DHCP range); all devices get good bandwidth.

Then, after a while (not sure whether after a given time, or after connecting another device) the two routers start rebooting every minute. They reboot, wait exactly a minute, and then reboot again.  This goes on forever and makes using them completely impossible.

At some point (quite probably the same one) they stop being accessible from the network via their IP addresses, even though they still show up in the network-connected list of the main router with the same IP addresses I configured them with.

I have fixed the Wi-Fi channel in case they were hunting for better channels, but no difference.  And looking at the system logs all I can see are the messages since the restart, and nothing to show why they might have rebooted.

Any help/pointers you can give would be very gratefully received!

Comment: I connect routers like this, and I can always resolve connection issues. If something happens with network connectivity, routers do not reboot (I may need restart routers after I have resolved issues).  TRY:  Updating the firmware in your devices.

Comment: Many thanks.  I did wonder about updating firmware but couldn't find anywhere to download the most recent version.  Any pointers for that?

Comment: These are old consumer routers and I only saw D-Link articles on how to upgrade the firmware. You can try: http://semantic.gs/d_link_dsl_3680_firmware_driver_v2_download  .  You might also consider newer hardware. It could be a hardware issue in the old router (one or both) causing the restarts.

Comment: I tried that site but the download is just 3k and then the "driver manager/finder" that it instructs me to install next flashes up a virus error.

Comment: not sure whether it can be hardware since both seem to work OK when only one switched on...  thanks

Comment: Don't trust a site that requires "driver finder" software. . You don't need some 3rd party tool to find the firmware, you just need the direct file download.

Comment: The routers are old so it may be conflicts with modern stuff and lack of firmware is an issue. At this point, consider replacing them.

Comment: can't find firmware anywhere :-(

Comment: any suggestions for replacements John?  I was trying to re-use common old routers to save money and landfill.  what would you go for?  thanks